# What to copy for a .Net Core console application publish?

Tags: .net-core, publish

I have an incredibly simple .NET core console application that I'd like to publish into a self contained executable.  My application uses an the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json package so I can use an appsettings.json file.

From the command line, in the .csproj folder, I run

`dotnet publish --self-contained true -r win-x64`

.  Inside my Debug folder, I see a netcoreapp2.1 folder and then the win-x64 folder.  Inside that folder, I see the following:

```
publish -> folder
myapp.deps.json
myapp.dll
myapp.exe
myapp.pdb
myapp.runtimeconfig.dev.json
myapp.runtimeconfig.json
appsettings.json
hostfxr.dll
hostpolicy.dll
```

Am I supposed to copy just the files from this directory or do i have to copy the entire publish folder along with the files to my destination on a Windows Server? Or did I miss a switch to condense these items down further so movement from server to server is even simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying just the files from the win-x64 directory was not enough.  I needed to copy up the entire publish folder and run the application from that directory, otherwise error messages such as not being able to find a dependency would occur.